# Is there a ‘functional’ notation for $a^x$?

Tags: notation, exponential-function

The notation $\exp(x)$ can be used in place of $e^x$, which is useful in two ways:

- For messy exponents, the former notation is more readable.
- It is useful to be able to describe the function $\exp$ in the abstract (as opposed to the value of that function at $x$).

Does a similar notation exist for $a^x$? Writing $\exp(x\log a)$ seems too cumbersome, so perhaps something like $\exp_a(x)$ is better.

Comment: I don't know of a standard notation for this. $\mapsto$ notation is often useful for giving an expression for an anonymous function making it clear what the argument is. So does $x \mapsto a^x$ work for you?

Comment: Using $\exp_{a}$ is parallel to $\log_{a}$ for the base-$a$ logarithm, and is what I'd have suggested based on your title.

Comment: @RobArthan: That is a nice notation, and it is probably more common that $\exp_a(x)$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: I do like this notation, but I'm unsure how common it is. Have you seen $a^x$ written as $\exp_a(x)$ in a textbook, journal etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments:

- I've [used the notation myself](https://www.ams.org//open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110758) in an undergraduate-level analysis manuscript.
- Can't swear if I've seen $\exp_{a}$ used by other authors. By contrast, $\log_{a}$ is reasonably common in calculus books, and not uncommon in the literature, especially $\log_{2}$ and $\log_{10}$, but sometimes even $\log_{e}$.
- In school many years ago, I recall books would create *ad hoc* named functions, similar to what Rob Arthan suggests, e.g., "Let $f(x) = b^{x}$...." Rogawski-Adams (the nearest calculus book at hand) does this, though they do use $\log_{b}$.
- No matter what notation you settle on, the Right Way to handle the coding in LaTeX is to create and use a dedicated macro, e.g., `\newcommand{\Exp}[1][]{\exp_{#1}}`. If your journal or book series has style requirements, your manuscript can be made compliant by changing a single line of preamble code instead of by lengthy search-and-replace.